# When I opened the web page I downloaded before ,a http:// get became a file:/// get,why?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, web

I downloaded a web page named map.html which was a web app using Google apis.There was a marker on it.
However,when I opened the local one in the browser,the marker disappeared.And I checked the "developer tools" ,just to find out **a get request from http:// had  turned into file:/// .**
So it accounted for the html not working .The marker.png was on the  google web server.And apparently it can't be found on my computer.The weird thing was I opend the original web page and found out the marker.png in the "resource" in  developer tools with a link to http://.

The question was how to solve this problem.There was no explicit link to file:// in the html indeed .

Answer (score 0):

Because earlier you were requesting the page from the server over HTTP and now when you are opening the saved page you are requesting to open the page from your local file system.

For the image, download the image on your computer and then change the HTML code for the image to use the local image. This means you need to modify the "src" attribute of the  tag in your html file.

Comment: Thanks for helping.The question is that there is no img tag at all.It containes some javascript and post requests to google to use the api.  In fact in the resources there are many images all of which on the google server except from this one linked to file://.Is it a flaw of google's map api？